# This LINQ-to-Entities join seems overly complex, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, sybase

I have two queries that I need to combine in LINQ that both actually come from the same table. The reason for this is that one of the queries needs to get the max of a field for each day and then sum the days together where the second query can just sum everything right off the bat. Here is the first query:

```
var queryDownload = from p in
                        (from p in almdbContext.cl_contact_event
                         where p.time_of_contact >= startDate && p.time_of_contact < endDate && p.input_file_name.Contains(inputFileName) && listName.Contains(listName)
                         group p by new
                         {
                             date = EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(p.time_of_contact.Value.Year, p.time_of_contact.Value.Month, p.time_of_contact.Value.Day, 0, 0, 0),
                             listName = p.contact_list_name
                         } into g
                         select new
                         {
                             date     = g.Key.date,
                             listName = g.Key.listName,
                             download = g.Max(a => a.total_number_of_records)
                         })
                    group p by p.listName into g
                    select new
                    {
                        listName      = g.Key,
                        totalDownload = g.Sum(a => a.download),
                    };
```

This is the second:

```
var queryPenData = from p in almdbContext.cl_contact_event
                   where p.time_of_contact >= startDate && p.time_of_contact < endDate && p.input_file_name.Contains(inputFileName) && listName.Contains(listName)
                   group p by p.contact_list_name into g
                   select new
                   {
                       listName           = g.Key,
                       dials              = g.Sum(a => a.ov_dial_start_time != null ? 1 : 0),
                       agentConnects      = g.Sum(a => a.agent_login_name != null ? 1 : 0),
                       abandons           = g.Sum(a => a.response_status == "DAC" || a.response_status == "DAD" ? 1 : 0),
                       rightPartyContacts = g.Sum(a => a.response_status == "PTP" || a.response_status == "RPC" ? 1 : 0),
                       promiseToPays      = g.Sum(a => a.response_status == "PTP" ? 1 : 0),
                       talkTime           = g.Sum(a => EntityFunctions.DiffSeconds(a.ov_call_connected_time, a.ov_trunk_released_time)) ?? 0,
                       wrapTime           = g.Sum(a => EntityFunctions.DiffSeconds(a.ov_trunk_released_time, a.record_released_time)) ?? 0
                   };
```

And this is the query joining them together.

```
var queryJoin = from qd in queryDownload
                join qp in queryPenData
                on qd.listName equals qp.listName
                select new
                {
                    listName           = qp.listName,
                    download           = qd.totalDownload,
                    dials              = qp.dials,
                    agentConnects      = qp.agentConnects,
                    abandons           = qp.abandons,
                    rightPartyContacts = qp.rightPartyContacts,
                    promiseToPays      = qp.promiseToPays,
                    talkTime           = qp.talkTime,
                    wrapTime           = qp.wrapTime
                };
```

This seems extremely verbose/roundabout to me. Is there a better way I can write/approach this to shrink/simplify the code?

Comment: FYI I never use the lambda syntax (your last example) as it's not very readable especially with multiple joins. When doing joins I always use the expression syntax (your first few examples).

Additionally you comment that your examples are verbose, I don't see a significantly shorter way to write this in TSQL.

Comment: @Nick I actually really wanted to avoid it but I couldn't figure out any other way to make it work. When dealing with queries I definitely prefer to use the expression syntax over the method syntax as it just "makes sense."

Comment: Not being big on L2EF, could those summations be exchanged with conditional counts?

Comment: @Nick Yeah, I mean it just seems way long for a relatively simple join. Esp the part where I write out the anonymous type twice.

Comment: @sixlettervariables I actually had a previous question that had pretty much this exact query in it without the join. In that question I was trying to do- .Count(a => a.ov_dial_start_time != null) which, IMO, made the code clearer. However, the Sybase driver doesn't translate it properly and it throws an error.

Comment: @Kittoes: I've added the Sybase tag to make sure future readers understand that particular limitation. L2EF/L2S are picky depending on which driver you use, so it helps to tag it accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your last query could you not just do something like this?

`var queryJoin = from qd in queryDownload join qpd in queryPenData on qd.listname equals qpd....`

Should be able to do this:

```
var queryJoin = from qd in queryDownload
            join qp in queryPenData
            on qd.listName equals qp.listName
            select new
            {
                qp, qd
            };
```

From what I can tell you've already formed your data in `queryPenData` so there is no reason to re-assign it to new variables in the final join. Just select the object which will allow you to traverse into the anonymous type in `queryPenData`. I think...

Comment: I could swear I tried that before and I guess I messed up the syntax somewhere because it works perfectly now. Much better than the method call I had before, thanks! Now is there any way I can do this without the two nearly identical anonymous types?

Comment: the only thing I don't like about that is that the anonymous type created is an anonymous type containing two other anonymous types instead of a truly combined one.

Comment: If you want a specific type you're going to have to create a backing class that contains the same properties. It's a bit difficult for me to suggest anything else without all of the code and environment infront of me to test with.